# Tabs in Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, c#, tabs, monaco-editor

How do I make tabs in the Monaco editor like Visual Studio Code? For example, this is what I mean. 
[image]

Answer (score 13):

There is a quite good explanation on [monaco-editor GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/604).

The tab is just a visual representation of Radio Button or Simple Button for example, where you have to subscribe onChange event. In the event handler, you have to update the model and view state, e.g. switching between foo.js & foo1.js files.

```
editor.setModel(data[desiredModelId].model);
editor.restoreViewState(data[desiredModelId].state);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the requirement for Monaco editor with tabs and built this project which you can use as the license is MIT:

https://github.com/bootrino/reactoxide

Comment: this project was archived in November 2022 and so is no longer an answer.